# Remap a CSV structure using Groovy

Tags: java, csv, groovy

I tried creating some scripts but everything looks too long and cumbersome and highly non-efficient.
Could you share an idea of how to do that most efficiently?

**Case description:**

- Three input files (Pipe delimited)
- Each file has a different header, but many of these fields are common = they have the same field name
- I created a generic header. I.e., header combining fields of all three files.
- Headers are not present in the data, but stored in variables e.g. String Header1 = "XXX"

**Below is a sample structure:**

```
Header of File 1:
Title|Postcode|Forename|Address2|Surname|Birthday|Address1|Address3|Addres4|
Header of File 2:
Title|Surname|Forename|Address1|Birthday
Header of File 3:
Title|Forename|Surname|Address1|Address2|Postcode|LicencePlate

The generic structure I need individual fields to be remapped to:
Title|Forename|Surname|Address1|Address2|Address3|Address4|Postcode|Birthday|LicencePlate
```

**The goal** is to output the reformated data in a format defined by the generic header. Fields which are missing in the individual file will be empty in the resulting structure.

The data I will be working with have: File 1-3 have each around 800 fields, generic structure have 1300 fields, where approx 450 of them are identical in all three files, the rest is unique for the particular file.

**Sample data below:**

```
File 1 input:
Mr|AJX 11E|John|Dummy Town|Doe|11/12/1972|15 Dummy Street|Dummy County|Dummy Country|
Mrs|XX A54|Evelin|Test Town|Blond|5/3/2001|3 Test Street|Test County|Test State|

File 1 output: 
Mr|John|Doe|15 Dummy Street|Dummy Town|Dummy County|Dummy Country|AJX 11E|11/12/1972||
Mrs|Evelin|Blond|3 Test Street|Test Town|Test County|Test State|XX A54|5/3/2001||

File 2 input:
Mr|Doe|John|15 Dummy Street|11/12/1972|
Mrs|Blond|Evelin|3 Test Street|5/3/2001|

File 2 output:
Mr|John|Doe|15 Dummy Street|||||11/12/1972||
Mrs|Evelin|Blond|3 Test Street|||||5/3/2001||

File 3 input:
Mr|John|Doe|15 Dummy Street|Dummy Town|AJX 11E|AJX 11E|
Mrs|Evelin|Blond|3 Test Street|Test Town|XX A54|XX A54|

File 3 output:
Mr|John|Doe|15 Dummy Street|Dummy Town|||AJX 11E||AJX 11E|
Mrs|Evelin|Blond|3 Test Street|Test Town|||XX A54||XX A54|
```

Thank you for suggestions

Edit: 
Here is my code based on real data: [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk6p6wn2spqhsek/CSV-remap.groovy?dl=0) and headers file - [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p115vneloelmzp/HeaderRows.txt?dl=0).
The code uses proprietary attributes of the software we use (e.g. "job.'descriptor'") These attributes just contain values in Strings. In the code, I check whether the data they sent are valid - e.g. Whether field count is identical to the header, removing duplicate fields from the header, then some additional checks.

Comment: what is the problem? what a suggestion do you need?

Comment: Generally, how best to store each header into arrays, how to mark the indexes where the field position is and where it should be afterwards and then executing the remapping for each line / field..
I can provide my code which handles similar things, but there are also added several additional checks e.g. removing duplicate fields. 
I would like to see the idea of other people as my code is really cumbersome and not efficient - e.g. I iterate the original file too many times.

Comment: are you using any library to read/write csv?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  Also +1 on the library
front - unless you are facing three liners like this, splitting strings
usually won't cut it (e.g. real world data has need for quoting the
separator etc)

Comment: Here is the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk6p6wn2spqhsek/CSV-remap.groovy?dl=0 and headers file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p115vneloelmzp/HeaderRows.txt?dl=0 
The code uses proprietary attributes of the software we use (e.g. "job.'descriptor'") These attributes just contain values in Strings.
In the code, I check whether the data they sent are valid - e.g. Whether field count is identical to the header, removing duplicate fields from the header, then some additional checks.
@daggett No I am not using any libraries for CSV, just file methods.

Comment: @cfrick I know how CSV should look like, trust me, I work on data automation for printing company for quite some time now. The problem is that its not always possible to get perfect data from clients. They often refuse to give us CSV in format "field1","field2"... but have their own systems which work certain way and they refuse to change it. This is exactly the case so pipe -delimited files are no exceptions for us.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62392729/edit) question and add the code there.

Comment: @cfrick Sure, I put it into also into the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about mapping values according to the generic header.

i'm not covering where to store all those headers and how to find correct one for incoming file.

So, here just a simple mapping

```
String [] genericHeader = 'Forename|Surname|Title|Address1|Address2|Address3|Address4|Postcode|Birthday|LicencePlate'.split('\\|',-1)

//convert header to a map: name->index for faster access
Map<String,Integer> header = 'Title|Forename|Surname|Address1|Address2|Postcode|LicencePlate'.split('\\|',-1).toList().withIndex().collectEntries()

//mapper - array of indexes: null = empty field, 0+ = index where to take the value
Integer[] mapper = genericHeader.collect{ header[it] }

//could be new File(filename).newReader("UTF-8")
Reader reader = new StringReader('''\
Mr|John|Doe|15 Dummy Street|Dummy Town|AJX 11E|AJX 11E
Mrs|Evelin|Blond|3 Test Street|Test Town|XX A54|XX A54
''')

//could be new File(filename).newWriter("UTF-8")
Writer writer = new StringWriter()

//process reader, remap each line, write it to writer
reader.eachLine{String line->
    String [] row = line.split('\\|',-1)
    writer << mapper.collect{ it==null ? "" :row[it] }.join('|') << '\n'
}

writer.flush()
writer.close()

//print for test
println writer.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is kind the suggestion I was looking for. I haven't worked with maps, collections etc. I go play with the code and try to find what these methods are doing. I will get back with feedback.

Comment: Thank you again, your solution works great. It is the true Groovy way :)